# Activator clean compile stage not getting completed in docker

Tags: docker, playframework, dockerfile, docker-machine, typesafe-activator

I am able run my project in development mode in docker.
but when switching to production mode compilation is not getting completed.

activator clean compile stage

I use
Playframework,activator,docker

Do we have any solution for it

FROM openjdk:8

ENV PROJECT_HOME /usr

RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_HOME/activator $PROJECT_HOME/app

WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME/activator

RUN wget https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.2/typesafe-activator-1.3.2.zip && 
unzip typesafe-activator-1.3.2.zip

ENV PATH $PATH:$PROJECT_HOME/activator/activator-1.3.2
ENV PATH $PATH:$PROJECT_HOME/app/target/universal/stage/bin
COPY . $PROJECT_HOME/app

WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME/app

CMD ["activator","clean","stage"]

EXPOSE 9000 8888

Comment: Please add more details. When you say "not getting completed", what exactly is happening? Does the process hang? Is it returning an error message? Does it finish but with unexpected results?

Comment: It does hang and stops responding

Comment: When I run
docker run test activator clean stage
its working fine.
But when I execute it inside the dockerFile as CMD it gets stopped in the mid of the compilation
CMD ["activator","clean","stage"]

Comment: Please include the `Dockerfile` and the output that you get when you run it. In general, to get a good answer on Stack Overflow, you need to include enough details for someone to be able to investigate. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have included the DockerFile